# Problems compiling FORTRAN program

Tags: compilation, makefile, fortran, gfortran

I have to compile Fortran programs but I haven't managed to do it.
I'm not an experienced person in this topic but I've tried to make some changes in the makefile, unfortunately the problem persists.

The original makefile was:

```
CC = cc
F77 = f77
CFLAGS = -g -DSOLARIS -DDEBUG   #-DINTEL -DFREEBSD  #-DDEBUG
FFLAGS = -g -c
OBJDIR= ../bin
LIB = ./sub/libsaito.a

all: shearSAITOniu shearsaito.li shearsaito shearsaito.2 \
#   shearsaito run.saito saito

shearSAITOniu: shearSAITOniu.f  ${LIB}
    f77 shearSAITOniu.f -e -o ${OBJDIR}/shearSAITOniu -g ${LIB}

shearsaito.li: shearsaito.li.f  ${LIB}
    f77 shearsaito.li.f -e -o ${OBJDIR}/shearsaito.li -g ${LIB}

shearsaito: shearsaito.f ${LIB}
    f77 shearsaito.f -e -o ${OBJDIR}/shearsaito ${LIB}

shearsaito.2: shearsaito.2.f  ${LIB}
    f77 shearsaito.2.f -e -o ../bin/shearsaito.2 -g ${LIB}

qsaito.li: qsaito.li.f ${LIB}
    f77 qsaito.li.f -e -o ${OBJDIR}/qsaito.li ${LIB}

forward: forward.f ${LIB}
    f77 forward.f -e -o ${OBJDIR}/forward ${LIB}

#shear3d: shear3d.f ${LIB}
    f77 shear3d.f -e -o shear3d ${LIB}

#run.saito: run.saito.f ${LIB}
    f77 run.saito.f -o run.saito ${LIB}

#s_saito:   s_saito.f ${LIB}
#   f77 s_saito.f -o s_saito ${LIB}
```

Then I made a change in CCFLAGS replacing -DSOLARIS with -D_LINUX.
After doing make it appears the error message:

> f77 shearSAITOniu.f -e -o ../bin/shearSAITOniu -g ./sub/libsaito.a
>       /usr/bin/f77: Illegal option: -e
>       make: *** [shearSAITOniu] Error 255

I'm not sure about the meaning of this error message but I also tried to replace the f77 compiler with gfortran and get this error:

> gfortran shearSAITOniu.f -e -o ./shearSAITOniu -g ./sub/libsaito.a
>       gfortran: error: ./shearSAITOniu: No existe el archivo o el directorio
>       make: *** [shearSAITOniu] Error 1

I think that this programs were compiled originaly in a 32-bit machine, mine is 64-bit, but I don't know how exactly this affects. I hope you could help me solving this issue, thanks.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

To compile the program `shearSAITOniu` with `gfortran`, use the commandline:

```
gfortran shearSAITOniu.f -ffree-form -o ./shearSAITOniu -g ./sub/libsaito.a
```

This will solve the error:

```
gfortran: error: ./shearSAITOniu: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

but not necessarily other errors you have not yet discovered.

This is the reason for that error:

`-e` is an option of the `f77` compiler that
means: *Accept extended length input source lines*.

`-o` *filename* is an option of both the `f77` and `gfortran` compilers that
means: *Create output file "filename"*.

`-e` *symbol* is an option of the `gfortran` compiler (strictly, the linker)
that means: *Make symbol "symbol" the entry point of the program*.

For both the `f77` and the `gfortran` compilers a filename that appears
on the commandline that is not preceded by the option `-o` is interpreted
as naming an input file for compiling or linking.

Therefore what the failing commandline:

```
gfortran shearSAITOniu.f -e -o ./shearSAITOniu -g ./sub/libsaito.a
```

means to `gfortran` is: *Compile and link the input files* `shearSAITOniu.f`, `./shearSAITOniu`
*and* `./sub/libsaito.a`; *insert debugging information in the resulting program* (`-g`),
*and make symbol* `-o` *the entry point of the program.*

The `-o` is interpreted as the *symbol* of the option `-e` *symbol*, and `./shearSAITOniu`
is interpreted as an input file, which does not exist.